# Control 12V pump with Raspberry Pi through relay

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, 12v, 5v

I'm building a small project where I will control a 12V water pump with my raspberry Pi.

I have made a small sketch of what I imagine should be a correct setup, but have been reading about the need for a flyback diode.

I'm new to electricity, so I'm not sure how to connect this. I just bought a pack of 1N4007 diodes. How should I connect it so that it protects my Raspberry Pi/relay from any arcs?

[image]

I have the following relay: [image]

Should I remove the jumper between COM/GND to separate the two power sources through the optocoupler?

Appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Comment: It'd be a good idea to post a link to the documentation for the relay board, but it looks to me like it has flyback diodes - it's probably the component on the bottom left of each relay.

Comment: I think the relay board has a flyback diode incorporated. Do you have any data sheet for the relay board?

Comment: It would be a good idea to decide if you are going to switch the mains to the mains adaptor ("charger") or the low voltage to the pump. And is that mains adapter also being used to power the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @PeterJ diode indicated is likely for the relay coil, not the load. An additional diode for the pump and possibly also a snubber circuit would be advisable.

Comment: Hi! Sorry but their seems to be no documentation on this relay besides the product info on the sales page: Max per relay: 250 V AC/10 A, 30 V DC/10 A.

@AndrewMorton The 5V mains adapter is for the raspberry pi only, and then I have a separate 12V mains adapter for the water pump. I have gone with this route just to be safe since my knowledge on electrics is somewhat limited as of now. If I could power both with the 12V-Mains adapter that would be great ofcourse.

Comment: @Trevor I have bought a pack of 1N4007 which I have read should work fine for this. Could you please direct me as of where to place this diode in relation to my(awful) diagram above? :-)

Comment: Diode should be across the motor terminals, cathode to the PLUS side, anode to the negative side.

Comment: ISTR reading that the COM and GND may be mislabelled on those boards, so check with a multimeter for which is *really* which. Removing the jumper would be a good idea as there is no need for the circuits separated by the optoisolator to be connected.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I presume COM is the common for the 4 inputs, while GND is the ground for the 5V supply. If so, then surely the link should be kept in place?

Comment: AndrewMorton I guess the jumper is for selecting to power the relays terminals with the 5V? 

@Trevor does this placement look correct? [link] https://preview.ibb.co/iyhwBk/lillerasp_kopia.png [/link]

Comment: YEs, though hard to see if you got the polarity right on that image. Band on the diode should be to the left.

Comment: Thanks! I will get back with an update after its been connected tonight.

Comment: @klasmack Yes, it does, my mistake. I was confused by the lack of a visible terminal for a separate relay power supply (like in [Not sure how to wire my 5VDC to 120VAC arduino relay board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18939/36731)).

Comment: I have now tested the setup, and while keeping the jumper in place the setup works. When removing it however, I cannot switch the relay on. Any ideas what the jumper function could be? Am I now powering my pump via the 5V? I have connected according to above picture, with VCC and GND from raspberry to relay. And the Jumper is marked COM/GND.

Comment: Does it seem likely that Vcc-GND is the relay coil power and IN1...IN4-COM is for the control signals? So you can have a completely separate, less-well regulated 5 V supply for the relay coils rather than possibly disturbing/overloading the 5 V supply of the RPi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diode needs to be placed across the motor as shown in the crude diagram below. The diode should be placed as near to the motor as reasonably possible. This will reduce the wear from arcing across the relay contacts, as you have read.

What you should *also* try to do is prevent the sudden current change when a relay is energised from affecting the Raspberry Pi - you don't want it to have any chance of experiencing a voltage drop ("brown out") that resets it.

You can do that by using separate wires to the 5 V PSU and placing a decoupling capacitor (maybe 33 µF or whatever you have to hand around that value, or you can go and find out how to calculate the minimum required value) across Vcc-GND as close to the pins for them on the relay board as reasonably possible. The capacitor acts as a little reservoir of energy right next to where it is needed. For best results when doing that, also separate the common ground of the optoisolators from the relay coil ground.

I tried to emphasize that the power to the relay board and the power to the RPi should be kept separate in this circuit diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5mock.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A bit of heatshrink to put over any wire-to-wire solder connections that you make might be a good idea to keep things safe and tidy - it's less messy than electrical tape.