# Trying to understand powering relay with Raspberry Pi and 12 V electronics

Tags: power-supply, relay, raspberry-pi

I have a 12 V peristaltic pump, Raspberry Pi, computer PSU, And a [4-channel 5 V relay](https://www.sainsmart.com/products/4-channel-5v-relay-module). I have removed the jumper across jdvcc and bcc. My plan is to power the pump with the 12 V rail on my power supply and control the relay with the Raspberry Pi but also have 5 V from the 5 V rail on the PSU to power the relay.

Here is a crude drawing of my plan.

[image]

Does this seem correct?

I also looked at this question but it seems the method above is better because there is more isolation?
[Control 12V pump with Raspberry Pi through relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326423/control-12v-pump-with-raspberry-pi-through-relay).

Comment: A picture is nice but it doesn't cut the mustard in terms of whether the device is wired up correctly. We deal with electronics design on this site and without any link back to a schematic, this questions is asking answerer's to take a guess. In other words, it isn't a design question and it's not even a product support question without knowledge of the circuit board. However, this sort of product support question is usually off-topic.

Comment: Without some more information this is going to be difficult to give any guess on... At first glance I'd say that you may have a problem using two different 5v supplies and not connecting the grounds together somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh great, a 'manual' consisting of just a schematic with no component values. :(

Here is a part of it:-

[image]

Your wiring looks OK. VCC and IN(x) should go to the Rpi. JD-VCC and GND should go directly to the power supply via separate wires. To prevent a possible [ground loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)) you should **not** connect GND to the Rpi.

It might be more convenient to connect Rpi 5 V to the VCC pin on the input connector rather than the jumper block.